# Django: performing a SQL match all in Django

Tags: django, django-models, sql-match-all

I recently asked [how to solve a simple SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102907/can-you-solve-this-simple-sql-query). Turns out that there are [many solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation).

After some benchmarking i think this is the best one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Camera.*
FROM Camera c
     INNER JOIN cameras_features fc1 ON c.id = fc1.camera_id AND fc1.feature_id = 1
     INNER JOIN cameras_features fc2 ON c.id = fc2.camera_id AND fc2.feature_id = 2
```

Now, I've not clue how to perform this query with Django ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exactly this query you can execute this in django like raw sql. [**Here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) you can find about raw sql in django.

It`s good to put your sql code into a custom manager. An example with manager and raw sql can be found [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)