# How to Refine the Search Results with Django/python

Tags: django

I am using the customized mysql query i.e, (using more than one table with use of "JOIN" in the query) Then I got the Results. But now i want to refine the given result. How is it possible ?. kindly answer me if you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result returned should be a query set with field names so try this

```
result = some_query...
result = result.filter(field_name__lte=value)
result = result.exclude(field_name='EXPIRED')
```

You can replace **field_name** with an actual field_name.  Its all highlighted here.

[Django querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

But essentially when you have a queryset you can run filters or excludes on it to refine the queryset.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) to perform your custom SQL as it will return QuerySet that can be further filtered. If you are using [`raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries), you won't be able to do anything else with the result.

Here's a similar question addressing the problem: [Django: filter a RawQuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135678/django-filter-a-rawqueryset)