# Convert django RawQuerySet to Queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-managers

I have 2 Django models, `ModelA` with an `ArrayField` that is used to store a large list of primary key values (possibly 50k+ list)

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pk_values = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())

class CustomManager(manager.Manager):

    def get_for_index(self, index_id):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        obj = ModelA.objects.get(pk=index_id)
        return qs.filter(id__in=obj.pk_values)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    # [...] some fields

    objects = CustomManager()
```

This works:

```
qs = ModelB.objects.get_for_index(index_id=1)
```

However, this would be super slow where "pk_values" is a large list.

So I tried doing raw SQL queries:

```
class CustomManager(manager.Manager):
    def get_for_index(self, index_id):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM myapp_model_b JOIN myapp_model_a ON myapp_model_b.id = ANY(myapp_model_a.pk_values) WHERE myapp_model_a.id = '%s'" % index_id
        return qs.raw(sql)
```

But this returns a `django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet` instance.

But with this, I cant do things like `queryset.values()` afterwards.

How can I convert this to a normal Django queryset?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Docs:

- ArrayField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield
- Custom Manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance
- Raw queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries

Comment: I might be missing something, but can you use a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: These are existing models .. so I cant change it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a [RawSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) expression:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(id__in=RawSQL(
    'SELECT unnest(a.pk_values) FROM app_modela a WHERE a.id = %s',
    [index_id]
))
```

Alternatively you can reproduce the exact query you have in your question with [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
ModelB.objects.extra(
    tables=['foo_modela'],
    where=[
        '"app_modelb"."id" = ANY("app_modela"."pk_values")',
        '"app_modela"."id" = %s',
    ],
    params=[index_id],
)
```

Comment: I just saw your answer... after I posted my update. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Update: I got something working using `.extra()`

```
class CustomManager(manager.Manager):
    def get_for_index(self, index_id):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        sql = "myapp_model_b.id IN (SELECT UNNEST(myapp_model_a.pk_values) FROM myapp_model_a WHERE myapp_model_a.id='%s')" % index_id
        return qs.extra(where=[sql])
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra