# How to convert this RawQuerySet into QuerySet?

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, django-orm

**EDIT**
I don't need this to be Django ORM at all, I just need `QuerySet` instead of `RawQuerySet`.

I'm having a hard time converting `SQL` query into `Django ORM`. 
The point is to reorder `QuerySet` of `Article` objects such that every and only every 4th `Article` has `permanent=True`.

This is the function:

```
def permanent_by_4(self):
        SQL = """SELECT
   id
FROM (
   SELECT
       id,row_number + (row_number - 1) / 3 as row_number
   FROM (
       SELECT
          id,row_number() OVER ()
       FROM articles_article
       WHERE permanent != True
   )s

   UNION

   SELECT
       id,4 * row_number() OVER ()
   FROM articles_article
   WHERE permanent = True
) s
ORDER BY row_number"""
        return Article.objects.raw(SQL)
```

The main problem is to get `row_number`.
I tried `F('row_number')` which doesn't get row_number.

Do you know how to convert it?

**EDIT**

```
SUBQUERY = """SELECT
       id,row_number + (row_number - 1) / 3 as row_number
   FROM (
       SELECT
          id,row_number() OVER ()
       FROM articles_article
       WHERE permanent != True
   )s

   UNION

   SELECT
       id,4 * row_number() OVER ()
   FROM articles_article
   WHERE permanent = True"""
        return Article.objects.annotate(row_number=RawSQL(SUBQUERY, ['row_number'])).order_by('row_number')
```

I'm trying to annotate queryset by `row_number` and then order by it but it returns `ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288076/convert-django-rawqueryset-to-queryset

Comment: @SauloAislan Thanks but the answer doesn't respect ordering which is crucial in my case.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191865/9313033 . The django database window function [RowNumber](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#rownumber) was introduced in django2.0.