# How to make a QuerySet with custom select in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm working on a project in python I'm kind of a beginner. I searched a bit on the Queryset but didn't found out how to do a custom select query. Here's the raw SQL query :

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(
    DATE_ADD(date_and_time, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(date_and_time) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d'
  ) as Week,
  device_type as 'Type of device',
COUNT(*) as Views FROM manage_history
GROUP BY Week, device_type;
```

How could I get the values but with a QuerySet ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a raw sql query. More details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Thank you very much I think I'll go with that. But do you know if it is possible to manipulate the SELECT part ? With the DATE_FORMAT and DATE_ADD, all the process to show formatted data. Is it possible to do it in the query or do I need to do it after obtaining the data ?

Comment: Of course you can do whatever you want with any columns in the raw sql :) https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp and 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

Answer (score 1):

Django's default manager gives you `RawQuerySet`:

```
>>> from api.models import Song
>>> Song.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM api_song')
<RawQuerySet: SELECT * FROM api_song>
```

In case of that you want exactly `QuerySet` to be returned, [Take a look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288076/convert-django-rawqueryset-to-queryset).