# Django: Admin - order results based on regular expression

Tags: python, sql, regex, django, django-admin

I have a problem where I want to order model rows in Django admin based on a number within a string and ignore the letters - like XX0345XX, X0346XXX, XXX0347XX. I'm thinking that I should probably use a regular expression for that. I have an SQL query (PostgreSQL) that returns what I want:

```
select * from mytable order by substring(my_field, '\d+')::int DESC
```

But I'm having trouble applying it to get the same result in the Django admin `get_queryset()`.
I've tried doing something like:

```
def get_queryset():
    return Model.objects.raw("select * from mytable order by substring(my_field, '\d+')::int DESC")
```

but the problem is that I'm not returning the right type this way. `Model.objects.raw('...')` returns   `RawQuerySet`, but `get_queryset()` should return `QuerySet` instance not `RawQuerySet` one, so I can't do it this way.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Azy_Crw4282, you can use `QuerySet.extra()` to run raw SQL queries and still have the results returned as a `QuerySet` instance.

Here's how I managed to do a regex based "ORDER BY" on objects in admin view, based on a number within a string. I.e. order fields like XX0345XX, X0346XXX, XXX0347XX, based on the number they contain - basically get a substring that matches `'\d+'` regular expression.

Just override the `get_queryset()` function in your `admin.ModelAdmin` class.

**Solution:**

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    sql_query = "CAST(substring(booking_reference, '\d+') as int)"
    bookings = Booking.objects.extra(select={'book_ref_digits': sql_query}).order_by('-book_ref_digits')
    return bookings
```

As far as I understand, it adds a new temporary field, e.g. `book_ref_digits` in the `QuerySet` object and then you can do `.order_by()` on that.

*Note: Using older version of Django 1.10.5*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .extra() method of to convert from a rawqueryset to a queryset, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

This example is taken from, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288076/convert-django-rawqueryset-to-queryset)

```py
class CustomManager(manager.Manager):
    def get_queryset():
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        sql = "myapp_model_b.id IN (SELECT UNNEST(myapp_model_a.pk_values) FROM myapp_model_a WHERE myapp_model_a.id='%s')" % index_id
        return qs.extra(where=[sql])
```

Comment: Thank you @Azy_Crw4282 ! Managed to solve it with `qs.extra()` in a very similar way. Will add an answer that uses regex to sort on digit in a string.

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept either of the answers so that the question can be marked as solved.