# Django Error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns "

Tags: python, sql, django, rawsql

The raw query itself is correct and I am able to get retrieve the rawqueryset from the db. I need to convert this into queryset for further processing and I am facing below error.

Creating corresponding django query was hard for me and that is why I created SQL query, got the raw query set and now attempting to convert it to query set for further processing.

I have changed django model names and table names for anonymity.

Here is the output of what I tried in django shell. I was able to execute the below query but getting the error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns" when I try to access "queryset" below.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
from xyz.models import *
value = '1.2.3.4'
queryset = Test1.objects.filter(id__in=RawSQL("SELECT DISTINCT ON (test1.start_time, test1.id) test1.id, test1.name, test1.start_time FROM test1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test2 JOIN test3 ON test2.test3_id = test3.id AND test3.value = %s JOIN test4 ON test2.test4_id = test4.id AND test4.test1_id = test1.id) ORDER BY test1.start_time DESC", params=[value]))
```

For readability I have formatted the query used below.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (test1.start_time, test1.id)
  test1.id,
  test1.name,
  test1.start_time
FROM
  test1
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      test2
      JOIN test3 ON test2.test3_id = test3.id
      AND test3.value = 'value'
      JOIN test4 ON test2.test4_id = test4.id
      AND test4.test1_id = test1.id
  )
ORDER BY
  test1.start_time DESC
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert raw queryset to queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994330/how-to-convert-raw-queryset-to-queryset)

Comment: No, I figured out why the query failed earlier. The query needs additional parameter "params" which needs to be passed to RawSQL(). Now once I got the query executed, I am trying to access "queryset" from above and see the error "Django Error “django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns ”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you are selecting too many columns which your filter condition does not require. You subquery must select only `Test1` table `id` field as you filter on `id` field. So basically you subquery should only project `id` field like this:

```
SELECT
  test1.id
FROM
  test1
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      test2
      JOIN test3 ON test2.test3_id = test3.id
      AND test3.value = 'value'
      JOIN test4 ON test2.test4_id = test4.id
      AND test4.test1_id = test1.id
  )
ORDER BY
  test1.start_time DESC
```

So your final queryset should be like:

```
queryset = Test1.objects.filter(id__in=RawSQL("SELECT test1.id FROM test1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test2 JOIN test3 ON test2.test3_id = test3.id AND test3.value = %s JOIN test4 ON test2.test4_id = test4.id AND test4.test1_id = test1.id) ORDER BY test1.start_time DESC", params=[value]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the RawSQL at all

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

queryset = Test1.objects.filter(
    Exists(Test2.objects.filter(
        test3__value=value,
        test4__test1_id=OuterRef('id')
    )
)
```

I'm not certain your django model names, so `test3`, `test4`, and `test1` may be a little different in your example.